# Javascript: How to check if two numbers exist in string? (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :

```
testString = "child 4 to 10 years old";
```

How to check if the string contains two (or more) numbers?

```
testString.match("??")
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Cerbrus question you linked is totally different from this. So I'm going to reopen this..

Comment: Hm, looks like I didn't read the other question properly. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would find a match if the string contains atleast two numbers.

```
testString.match(/(?:.*?\b\d+\b){2}/)
```

or

```
/(?:.*?\b\d+\b){2}/.test(str);
```

or

If you also want to deal with decimal numbers then try this,

```
/(?:.*?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b){2}/.test(str);
```

Comment: And maybe you know whats the regex for ONLY one number?

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (testString.match(/(\d+)/).length >= 2) {
```

Is a very simple/readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
"String0With1Some2Words3And4Integers0000".split('').reduce((val, acc) => (
    val  + (parseInt(acc) ? 1 : 0))
, 0)
```